# Nuxt js is starting in Linux vm but not in Docker container, why?

Tags: docker, npm, nuxt.js

I'm getting different results when starting a nuxt app from Windows subsystem for Linux and when I start the same app in Docker. I already dockerized some other apps, so I'm not entirely new with the concept.

**WSL**
[image]

Is listening for connections

**Docker**

[image]

Is giving me an exception

```
FROM node:12.16

ENV APP_ROOT /code

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
#ADD . ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm install
RUN npm build

EXPOSE 3000
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
#CMD npm run dev
CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

---

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'dev' ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle yourmonitor@1.0.0~predev: yourmonitor@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle yourmonitor@1.0.0~dev: yourmonitor@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle yourmonitor@1.0.0~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle yourmonitor@1.0.0~dev: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/code/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
9 verbose lifecycle yourmonitor@1.0.0~dev: CWD: /code
10 silly lifecycle yourmonitor@1.0.0~dev: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 info lifecycle yourmonitor@1.0.0~dev: Failed to exec dev script
12 verbose stack Error: yourmonitor@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server`
12 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
13 verbose pkgid yourmonitor@1.0.0
14 verbose cwd /code
15 verbose Linux 4.19.76-linuxkit
16 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
17 verbose node v12.16.1
18 verbose npm  v6.13.4
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error syscall spawn
21 error file sh
22 error errno ENOENT
23 error yourmonitor@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server`
23 error spawn ENOENT
24 error Failed at the yourmonitor@1.0.0 dev script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>The problem is seems to be a typo in the package.json file while creating the docker image.</s>

You are running below script outside of docker.

cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server

Running below script inside of docker.

cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch aerver

server -> aerver

You should check the package.json while building the docker image.

And a bit of advise. You should use dockers environment variables while working on containers no need to use cross-env like packages with containers it clearly making it harder to debug problems.

So your dockerfile should look like this.

```
FROM node:12.16

ENV APP_ROOT /code

ENV NODE_ENV development

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
#ADD . ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm install
RUN npm build

EXPOSE 3000
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
CMD npm run dev
```

And your dev script in package.json should look like this.

nodemon server/index.js --watch server

Edit: Wrong opinion removed because of bad screen.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me out. However I use docker-compose to mount the exact same folder as I use in WSL, which means there shouldn't be any code differences. Unless I'm missing something I think it's something else. I also checked and there is no "aerver" anywhere in config or code.

Comment: Sorry my bad, bad screen issue. From screenshot I read the letters wrong. Did you try it without cross-env? Does the error persist with dockers environment variable? Just curious.